# O que é uma exceção de primeira chance no .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, terminologia, exceção

O que exatamente é uma exceção de primeira chance (*first chance exception*)? Como e onde ele se origina em um programa .NET? E por que é chamado por esse nome peculiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falando em termos bem simples é uma forma de lidar com uma exceção através do *debugger* (até onde sei só tem no Visual Studio) mesmo que ela seja manipulada pela aplicação.

O objetivo primário é você saber que uma exceção ocorreu e talvez fazer algo antes e depois dela ser manipulada pela aplicação. Então dá a chance para o programador não só saber que houve a exceção, mas também fazer algo diferente enquanto está *debugando*.

Sem isso a aplicação funcionará dentro da normalidade esperada porque a exceção era esperada e existe um mecanismo no código para lidar com ela e não deve quebrar a aplicação, e em condições normais o IDE/*debugger* nem ficaria sabendo que ocorreu, porque se torna algo normal do código.

Você pode configurar como quer proceder quando acontecer algo assim (veja abaixo).

Se a exceção não é manipulada pela aplicação, o IDE/*debugger* terá a segunda chance de manipulá-la, já que a aplicação está prestes a quebrar. Essa não tem como escapar, pode só não deixar o *debugger* interceptar antes de quebrar.

Quando a exceção de primeira chance ocorre seu código fez algo excepcional (em tese, se a exceção foi usada de forma adequada), mas não necessariamente tem um problema no código.

Pode ocorrer só a segunda chance.

[image: Tela do VS onde configura]